# EntityFramework 5 install

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget, entity-framework-5

I created an ASP.NET MVC4 project in VS 2010, then decided I wanted the 4.5 framework so opened the project in VS 2012 and changed the target framework to 4.5.

I got some compile errors which I am fairly sure were caused by a reference to a version of EntityFramework below version 5.

Eg:

> Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\saad\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Models\AccountModels.cs 21 6 MvcApplication1

Here are the entries currently in my Web.config file:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```

and ...

```
<assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</assemblies>
```

I had no luck changing the EntityFramework reference to a higher version as it did not appear in the framework list.

Following some advice given to somebody with a similar problem, I tried to use the Package Manager Console to solve the problem. You can see the mess I've got into with it below.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this problem?

I do need version 5 for the work I am doing.

> PM> Uninstall-Package entityframework Successfully removed
>   'EntityFramework 5.0.0' from PersonalityTest_002. The directory is not
>   empty.
>
> Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
>
> PM> Install-Package entityframework Install-Package : The remote name
>   could not be resolved: 'nuget.org' At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  entityframework
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
>   PM> Install-Package EntityFramework 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' already
>   installed. The directory is not empty.
>
> Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'. Install-Package :
>   Failed to add reference to 'EntityFramework'. At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
>   PM> Install-Package entityframework 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' already
>   installed. The directory is not empty.
>
> Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'. Install-Package :
>   Failed to add reference to 'EntityFramework'. At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  entityframework
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
>   PM> Install-Package EntityFramework 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' already
>   installed. The directory is not empty.
>
> Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'. Install-Package :
>   Failed to add reference to 'EntityFramework'. At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
>   PM>  Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force Uninstall-Package :
>   Unable to find package 'EntityFramework'. At line:1 char:19
>   +  Uninstall-Package <<<<  EntityFramework -Force
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Uninstall-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UninstallPackageCommand
>   PM> Install-Package EntityFramework 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' already
>   installed. The directory is not empty.
>
> Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'. Install-Package :
>   Failed to add reference to 'EntityFramework'. At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
>   PM>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NuGet (if not, do) you may need to remove and add back all your packages so they switch to 4.5.  If you open your packages.config you can see the versions.

Comment: Thanks Trey. Yes, I was using NuGet. I ended up with no EntityFramework and even more compile errors than I started with. I have heard from other posts that frameworks 4 and 4.5 use a different version of EntityFramework 5 (?!!) hence the need to uninstall and reinstall it. So I think I was on the right track with what I did. Re-installing all the packages seemed like too much hard work so I have solved the problem by creating a new project in VS 2012. If someone else hits this problem and has a large project (mine luckily wasn't) they could may be copy the new proj settings over to the old.

Answer (score 0):

**TableAttribute** that caused error comes from:

```
Assembly System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll, v4.0.0.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
```

So you probably miss reference to this assembly in your project.

Comment: Thanks Nenad, I gave up in the end and created a new VS 2012 project.